# ¿Como mostrar los puertos de mi pc en un combobox c# windows form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, puertos

la verdad es que no se como empezar.
cuando hacemos click derecho y vamos a Administrador de dispositivos nos muestra en la puertos una lista de dispositivos conectados, ahora quiero saber como puedo llevar esa misma lista a mi combobox, trabajo en windowsForm c#:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola, todavia no lo he necesitado pero guardo este link por si lo necesito para acceder a ese tipo de elementos. http://www.highrez.co.uk/Downloads/InpOut32/default.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtener un listado de los puertos COM disponibles es muy sencillo,puedes hacer uso del método [`GetPortNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] puertos = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

Debes tener en cuenta que hay que añadir el espacio de nombres `System.IO.Ports`. Esto te devuelve en `puertosCom` un array con los nombres de los puertos serie disponibles en tu sistema.

En cuanto a los puertos LPT la cosa se complica, ya que no hay ningun método de .net que nos de esa información. Una posible solución es usar una query WMI:

```
var parallelPort = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_ParallelPort");
foreach (var rec in parallelPort.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(rec.Properties["Name"]);
}
```

(Lamentablemente esto último no puedo probarlo ya que no tengo disponible ningún equipo con puerto LPT)